# Android как заставить при нажатии на уведомление выполнить конкретное действие

Tags: java, android

Конкретно требуется в сервисе вызвать `notification` уведомление, и при нажатии на него запустить другой сервис. 
Проблема в том что я не могу разобраться, как сделать обработчик на уведомление. В интернете нашел только как при нажатии переключиться на активити через `intent` и `pendingIntent` или передать переменную на активити. 
Я не придумал ничего лучше, как отправить из `notification` переменную в активити, она ее ловит, смотрит что он не null и запускает новый сервис.
MyService.java:

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        sendNotification();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
     private void sendNotification() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PushToastActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("sendAction","runService");
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "127");

        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("aaa")
                .setContentText("bbb")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        Notification notification = builder.build();
        notificationManager.notify(131, notification);
    }
PushToastActivity.java

    public class PushToastActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_push_toast);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String fileName = intent.getStringExtra("sendAction");

        //Toast.makeText(this, fileName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(fileName)) {
            startService(new Intent(this, SecondService.class));
        }


    }

    public void startServiceClick(View view) {

        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));


    }
}
```

т.е. в `myService` в методе `onStartCommand` создаю уведомление и отправляю по нажатию на него строку, а в методе `onCreate` получаю эту строку и по условию запускаю новый сервис.
Собственно вопрос в том как это грамотно сделать обработчик нажатия на уведомление, чтобы так не колхозить?

---

кажется понял,  я же сервис запускаю и метод нужен соответствующий

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondService.class);
PendingIntent pIntent=PendingIntent.getService(this,0,intent,0);
```

единственное не понятен момент как вообще в принципе выполнить например какой то свой метод при нажатии на уведомление

Comment: Вы имеете в виду стартовать сервис минуя активити? Если про это - то создавайте интент и P-интент для сервиса, не для активити

Comment: можно уточнить , пробовал делать так Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondService.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0); указал нужный мне сервис но как его теперь запустить по нажатию на уведомление, или я что то не так понял

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondService.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent=PendingIntent.getService(this,0,intent,0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так уж устроен андроид. При нажатии на уведомление можно лишь запустить Intent, находящийся внутри PendingIntent. В зависимости от того что именно должен запустить Intent откроется активити или запустится сервис. Внутри оных вы можете выполнить какое-то действие, основываясь на переданном через Bundle Intent-а значение.

В вашем случае, видимо, вам надо запускать IntentService и в его методе `onHandleIntent()` исполнять какой-то код. После его исполнения сервис автоматически закроется.